# Block network requests in chrome extension mv 3

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I'm reading about chrome extension API feature to [read or block network requests](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/declarativeNetRequest/). I want to create an extension that will give to the user the ability to add sites to a list of restricted websites and that will block each request to each site that user add into this list.

If I understand I need to create some static ruleset files, but this means that I need to bundle the list with the extension and this isn't exactly what I want to achive.

In mv2 extensions there was the ability to block requests dynamically, but is this possible with mv3?

Is there any way with chrome api to block requests to a website using a local dynamic list of sites that is saved in local storage?

[Into the docs](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/declarativeNetRequest/#method-updateEnabledRulesets) isn't explained clearly how chrome will update the rules. My idea is to have a context menu that add a rule.

Comment: Use chrome.declarativeNetRequest.updateDynamicRules.

Comment: @wOxxOm ok, but how I pass the input from context menu to the API??

Comment: Just call the API [directly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68752645).

Comment: I saw your example, I think I will do as suggested and call the api directly. Just a doubt is about the ruleset. Is it required or I can avoid to create a default one? I want that the user add a site list, so my idea is to not provide any default rule. 
PS: If you can leave an answer I will accept it.

Comment: There's no need for static rules at all.

Comment: @wOxxOm ok, so I will just need to declare the permissions and to add the static pages that will replace the blocked sites in web accessible resources right?